# Removing space from string with regex

Tags: regex

I can find spaces in the following string:

> "____Input from ABC"  << please note there are 4 spaces at the beginning of this string

using this regex:

```
[a-z] [a-z]
```

How can I replace"t f" with "tf" and "m A" with "mA"? I guess I have to use groups but I don't remember how. Any advice would be appreciated.

**P.S.** Please note that there are 4 spaces at the beginning of the string I don't want to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the language you are using, you should have a "replace" function

You have to use capturing group, like so :

```
([a-z]) ([a-z])
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

and then use the function to get them back in the pattern you want :

```
newString = oldString.replace("([a-z]) ([a-z])", "\1\2")
```

\X reference the Xth group of parenthesis

Answer (score 3):

Just use `\s` and replace with empty string `""`. You could also use literal space which too will work perfectly. Just remember to use global flag.

That is, use `/\s/g` or `/ /g` and replace with `""`

---

Regarding your update, you could still use the above regex and then just add four spaces to the string, which is quite efficient. If you still want a regex, you could use

```
(?<=\w)\s(?=\w)
```

and replace with `""`(Empty string)

Answer (score 1):

use the regex : s/\s//g
this should work with perl.

```
echo "Input from ABC"|perl -pe 's/\s//g'
>InputfromABC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `(*SKIP)(*F)` like below,

```
^\s+(*SKIP)(*F)|\s
```

Then replace the matched spaces by empty string.

Answer (score 1):

in regular expression you can't replace value to another, you can detect certain character or whatever you put it in your expression after that you have you to do replace if that character detected.

```
 [a-z]+\\s
```

the above expression will detect the white-spaces after that you can decide to replace the string

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is to search this:

```
(^\s+)|\s+
```

and substitute with `$1` so the spaces at the beginning of the string will stay. Demo here:

https://regex101.com/r/qQ9dL9/1